# how to update a global variable in java from an anonymous class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the `lat` and `lng` of a users location and pass these as a double to another method. However, I don't know how to do this or is it is possible.

As soon as I exit the inner class the variable's become null again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Double lat;
    Double lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    public void onSearch(View v){
        String[] requiredPermissions = {
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        };

        boolean ok = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredPermissions.length; i++) {
            int result = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, requiredPermissions[i]);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ok = false;
            }
        }

        if (!ok) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 1);
            // that last parameter MUST be >0, or it fails silently
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            // doStuffThatNeedsPermissions();
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lng = location.getLongitude();

                    System.out.println("location is : " + lat + lng);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                }
            });

            //System.out.println("location is here is : " + lat + lng);
        }

        //System.out.println("location is dow here is : " + lat + lng);
    }

}
```

Comment: There are more ways to use outer class variables in an anonymous class. One of them `AtomicDouble`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the permission to leave a comment so that's why answered the question.

As far as I understood.Though there are so many ways.Here is a way how you can use this into your entire class.

```
private Double lat,lng;
...
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            YourClass.this.lat = location.getLatitude();
            YourClass.this.lng = location.getLongitude();

            System.out.println("location is : " + this.lat + this.lng);
        }
...


System.out.println("location is here is : " + this.lat + this.lng);
```

I edited my answer. I made a silly mistake.Sorry for that.

Comment: `new LocationListener() {` - anonymous class